# How to check a napi_value of type napi_number is an integer or decimal by using node.js N-API function,

Tags: c, node.js, n-api, node-nan, node-native-addon

How to check a given **napi_value** of type **napi_number** is an **integer** or **decimal** (a number with fractional value) by using node.js native N-API function .
Look like there is no isInt() or isDouble() equivalent function in N-API (we don’t want to use V8 function call either). Let us consider a scenario where we are calling a native addon function **f1()** from JavaScript by passing a JavaScript object as argument as shown in the snippet.

```
let obj = { n1: 123, n2: 123.45 };
myaddon.f1( obj );
```

The native function **f1()** want to extract value associated with the keys **n1** and **n2** by calling the best fit value extraction N-API function. For example to extract value of **n1** it may be best to use one of **napi_get_value_int*** and similarly for the **n2** the **double** is a better choice.

```
napi_get_value_double
napi_get_value_int32
napi_get_value_uint32
napi_get_value_int64
```

Unfortunately I could not find any N-API function to verify the **derivative of napi_number property**. Have you come across similar situation, if so how did you solve this problem?

https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/265

Answer (score 1):

A request has been opened with node-addon-api team regarding this feature and they provided an answer that sound logical. I thought of sharing the answer with this community that may help similar queries others may have. [Here is the answer from node-addon-api team](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/578)

> While handling [numbers](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value) with JavaScript, it is important to know
>   that all numbers in JavaScript are [double-precision 64 bit IEEE
>   754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) values (despite some engines like v8 might have additional
>   represents on small integers, there is no such definition in ECMA spec
>   and no way to determine these types of number in JavaScript).
>
> napi_get_value_{double,int32,uint32,int64} just convert these value to
>   its desired one. There might be a precision loss in the conversion. If
>   a determined number is required in the case, use BigInt instead.